# SQL Query help: pick newest record and join to another table

Tags: sql

I've been trying and trying without success to write a query in SQL Server 2012 that works here.

I have tblProducts that looks like this and has about 100000 rows:

```
SKU, Title, CategoryID
155, 'Product a', 5
176, 'Product b', 5
630, 'Product 1', 10
```

and tblPrices which looks like this and has about a million rows, each recording the price and stock of the item at a certain time:

```
SKU, Price, StockCount, TimeStamp (smalldatetime)
155, 10, 5, 2012-12-31 23:40:00
155, 9, 6, 2012-12-30 23:40:00
155, 7, 6, 2012-12-29 21:40:00
176, 0.50, 0, 2012-12-31 23:40:00
```

Basically, I want to get a list of the SKUs which are in category 5 and their current price is > 3.

So far, I've got:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPrices
WHERE Timestamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
    FROM tblPrices
    GROUP BY SKU
```

which gives me the current/newest price of each SKU in tblPrices:

```
SKU, Price, StockCount, TimeStamp
155, 10, 5, 2012-12-31 23:40:00
176, 0.50, 0, 2012-12-31 23:40:00
```

but what I really need is to filter this table by price, join it to tblProducts and then filter by category. However, no matter how I try this, it returns several rows for each SKU or ignores the price condition. The below returns multiple SKUs (thus missing the point of newest price must be > 3) and also takes about 2 minutes to execute and return 810 rows, about 1 in 4 of which are unique:

```
SELECT tblProducts.SKU , CategoryID
FROM tblProducts,

(SELECT EAN, Price
FROM tblPrices
WHERE Timestamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
    FROM tblPrices
    GROUP BY SKU
)) a

WHERE tblProducts.EAN = a.EAN AND tblProducts.CategoryID=5 AND a.Price > 3
```

I would be really grateful for any help, as I'm getting nowhere on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT SKU
FROM tblProducts
WHERE CategoryId = 5 AND SKU IN (
    SELECT SKU
    FROM tblPrices
    WHERE Price > 3 AND Timestamp IN (
        SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
        FROM tblPrices
        GROUP BY SKU
    )
)
```

Comment: I think the current price needs to be greater than 3. Probably max(timestamp) will be required at some point

Comment: @ChetterHummin: Ah, it's historical. Didn't catch that.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the response, but I need the newest price to be > 3

Comment: Thanks. Using the subquery in the where clause does work fine, but for some reason it takes such a long time to run (1:18 min). Is this wait really necessary?

Comment: Also, the INNEr JOIN code returned duplicate SKUs - one for every tblPrices row that matched SKU and Price > 3

Comment: @drspa44: Not sure - this was the first thing that came into my mind. Make sure that you have the proper indexes set up on your columns, too.

Comment: I've never come across indexes before, but I rebuilt the primary key indexes on these tables and the query now takes 0:59 to run. If I change the query to say CategoryID <> 5, it returns 17000 rows almost instantly. Would there be a way of returning the SKU and an unfiltered CategoryID, so that I can traverse it linearly in my program? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @drspa44: Sure, just remove the `CategoryID = 5` part in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that myself!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a CTE with `PARTITION BY SKU`  and `ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC` to get only a single row for each SKU with `CATEGORYID=5`:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
      PR.SKU, PR.Price, PR.StockCount, PR.TimeStamp, P.Title, P.CategoryID,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PR.SKU ORDER BY PR.TimeStamp DESC) AS RN
   FROM 
      tblProducts P 
      INNER JOIN tblPrices PR ON P.SKU=PR.SKU
   WHERE 
      p.CategoryID=5
      AND PR.Price > 3
)
SELECT 
   SKU, Price, StockCount, TimeStamp, Title, CategoryID
FROM 
   CTE
WHERE 
   RN = 1
```

The `CTE` is like a subquery and the `PARTITION BY` is similar to a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Wow, this filters results perfectly and is very fast! I've already implemented voithos's solution, but this will come in useful for similar queries I'll need. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @drspa44: Remember to accept an answer(usually the most helpful). Btw, happy new year :)

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Voithos with a *correlated* subquery.

```
 SELECT p.SKU, p.Price
 FROM tblPrices p
      Join tblProducts d 
           On d.sku = p.sku
 WHERE d.CategoryId = 5 
     And p.Price > 3
     AND p.Timestamp =
        (Select Max(TimeStamp)
         From tblPrices 
         Where Sku = p.sku)
```